# Can an unpowered 2.4 GHz transceiver exist?

Tags: low-power, rfid, transceiver

I just read an internal presentation from the company I work for announcing the release of a small consumer device with an embedded RFID tag and 2.4 GHz transceiver. The presentation made note of the fact that the device does not need to be turned on or off. I am assuming that means the device is unpowered, but I'm wondering about the feasibility of an unpowered transceiver.

Does such a transceiver exist (I could be wrong about it not needing a battery)? How much data could such a low-powered/unpowered transceiver transmit? Could it be used to fix a location within a wifi network?

Comment: it is standard practice for the RFID tag to be powered externally i.e. by the reader reading it. It does this by using its antenna i.e. electromaganetic waves

Answer (score 3):

It's probably passively powered.  RFID tags can have processors that are powered entirely by the energy derived from the RF signal used to query the tag.  The tag/processor combo can only function when the RF signal is present or if it stores energy from the RF signal then as long as that lasts.  Otherwise it just shuts down.  Typically it transmits its unique ID and possibly a small amount of other data.

Comment: The difference is that the RFID doesn't actually transmit a signal, it only loads the transmitting antenna, which requires far less power than actually transmitting.

Comment: @stevenvh could you explain that a little more?

Comment: @JGord - In the near field where RFID operates the transmitter can sense the load on the transmitted signal. If the tag's microcontroller switches a tuned circuit on and off the transmitter will see this as a dip in the output signal. So all the uC has to do to send a code is switch the tuned circuit on and off, which requires virtually no power; it just uses the power of the transmitter. If you really want to transmit a signal yourself you need to provide the power to be sent from the antenna. The further you want to go, the more power you need: distance x 2 = power x 4.

Comment: @AngryEE: You stated that it can transmit "possibly a small amount of other data", which implies this tag can be updated dynamically/"in-field" by a microcontroller/similar. I've never seen such interfaceable tags. What might these be called? Or could you suggest a link to one?

Comment: I was assuming the other data was static.  You can also create a microcontroller that mimics the function of an RFID tag in which case if you can get enough power to it you can do whatever you like.

Comment: @boardbite: Yes, some tags can be updated dynamically in the field. Typically such a "writable tag" has an unchangeable serial number in ROM and a writable EEPROM. [scanlime](http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/), [Mifare](http://www.itworldcanada.com/news/open-source-project-reveals-how-to-reprogram-rfid-cards-/04251), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501302/can-i-write-or-modify-data-on-an-rfid-tag , http://yro.slashdot.org/story/04/07/29/0321219/rfid-more-hackable-than-retailers-think , etc.

Comment: @boardbite http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/